# use of colon symbol in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am new to regex. I am studying it in regularexperssion.com. The question is that I need to know what is the use of a colon (:) in regular expressions.

For example:

```
$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/';
```

which matches:

```
$url1  = "http://www.somewebsite.com";
$url2  = "https://www.somewebsite.com";
$url3  = "https://somewebsite.com";
$url4  = "www.somewebsite.com";
$url5  = "somewebsite.com";
```

Yeah, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Colon `:` is simply colon. It means nothing, except special cases like, for example, clustering without capturing (also known as a non-capturing group):

```
(?:pattern)
```

Also it can be used in character classes, for example:

```
[[:upper:]]
```

However, in your case colon is just a colon.

**Special characters used in your regex:**

In character class `[-+_~.\d\w]`:

- `-` means `-`
- `+` means `+`
- `_` means `_`
- `~` means `~`
- `.` means `.`
- `\d` means any digit
- `\w` means any word character

These symbols have this meaning because they are used in a symbol class `[]`.
Without symbol class `+` and `.` have special meaning.

**Other elements:**

- `=?` means `=` that can occur 0 or 1 times; in other words `=` that can occur or not, optional `=`.

Comment: do you know the use of [-+_~.\d\w] ? in regex ?

Comment: great really helped ..:)

Comment: can ? be used for optional situations ?

Comment: @user3138386: It *is* used for symbols/element that are optional

Comment: @user3138386: Yes, that is exactly what it is used here for

Comment: @IgorChubin: Just a note: They're known as character classes, not symbol classes. :)

Comment: adding my vote for the explanation of non-capturing groups!

Answer (score 48):

I've decided to go you one better and explain the entire regex:

```
^                 # anchor to start of line
(                 # start grouping
 (                # start grouping
  [\w]+           # at least one of 0-9a-zA-Z_
  :               # a literal colon
 )                # end grouping
 ?                # this grouping is optional
 \/\/             # two literal slashes
)                 # end capture
?                 # this grouping is optional
(
 (
  [\d\w]          # exactly one of 0-9a-zA-Z_
                  # having \d is redundant
  |               # alternation
  %               # literal % sign
  [a-fA-f\d]{2,2} # exactly 2 hexadecimal digits
                  # should probably be A-F
                  # using {2} would have sufficed
 )+               # at least one of these groups
 (                # start grouping
  :               # literal colon
  (
   [\d\w]
   |
   %
   [a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
  )+
 )?               # Same grouping, but it is optional
                  # and there can be only one
 @                # literal @ sign
)?                # this group is optional
(
 [\d\w]           # same as [\w], explained above
 [-\d\w]{0,253}   # includes a dash (-) as a valid character
                  # between 0 and 253 of these characters
 [\d\w]           # end with \w.  They want at most 255
                  # total and - cannot be at the start
                  # or end
 \.               # literal period
)+                # at least one of these groups
[\w]{2,4}         # two to four \w characters
(
 :                # literal colon
 [\d]+            # at least one digit
)?
(
 \/               # literal slash
 (
  [-+_~.\d\w]    # one of these characters
  |              # *or*
  %              # % with two hex digit combo
  [a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
 )*              # zero or more of these groups
)*               # zero or more of these groups
(
 \?              # literal question mark
 (
  &amp;?         # literal &amp or &amp; (semicolon optional)
  (
   [-+_~.\d\w]
   |
   %
   [a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
  )
  =?             # optional literal =
 )*              # zero or more of this group
)?               # this group is optional
(
 #               # literal #
 (
  [-+_~.\d\w]
  |
  %
  [a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
 )*
)?
$                # anchor to end of line
```

It's important to understand what the metacharacters/sequences are.  Some sequences are *not* meta when used in certain contexts (especially a character class).  I've cataloged them for you:

### meta with no context

- `^` -- zero width start of line
- `()` -- grouping/capture
- `?` -- zero or one of the preceding sequence
- `+` -- one or more of the preceding sequence
- `*` -- zero or more of the preceding sequence
- `[]` -- character class
- `\w` -- alphanumeric characters and `_`.  Opposite of `\W`
- `|` -- alternation
- `{}` -- length assertion
- `$` -- zero width end of line

This excludes `:`, `@`, and `%` from having any special/meta meaning in the raw context.

### meta inside character class

`]` ends the character class.  `-` creates a range of characters unless it is at the start or the end of the character class or escaped with a backslash.

### grouping assertions

A `(?` combination starts a grouping assertion.  For example, `(?:` means group but do not capture.  This means that in the regex `/(?:a)/`, it will match the string `"a"`, but `a` is not captured for use in replacement or match groups as it would be from `/(a)/`.

`?` can also be used for lookahead/lookbehind assertions with `?=`, `?!`, `?<=`, `?<!`.  `(?` followed by any sequence except what I mentioned in this section is just a literal `?`.

Comment: I didnt get the use of  [-+_~.\d\w] ? please tell me

Comment: @ExplosionPills I stumbled on this thread while searching for the use of semicolon for non-capturing group, really appreciate your effort for answering this question, it is clear and neat. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

There is no special use for colon `:` in your case :

`(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?` will match `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`...

You can find one special use for colon : every capturing group starting by `(?:` won't appear in the results.
Example, with "foobarbaz" in input :

- `/foo((bar)(baz))/` => `{ [1] => 'barbaz', [2] => 'bar', [3] => 'baz' }`
- `/foo(?:(bar)(baz))/` => `{ [1] => 'bar', [2] => 'baz' }`

Answer (score 1):

A colon has no special meaning in Regular Expressions, it just matches a literal colon.

```
[\w]+:
```

This just means `any word character 1 or more times followed by a literal colon`
The brackets are actually not needed here. Square brackets are used to define a group of characters to match. So

```
[abcd]
```

means `a single character of a, b, c, d`

Comment: do you know the use of [-+_~.\d\w] ? in regex ? ?